# How can we select siblings using selector in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's a code snippet which uses jQuery to select siblings. I don't understand how it's going to fetch the siblings using different combinations in the **selector**. Below is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#main h1+h2').css("color", 'green');
  $('#main h2+p').css("color", 'green');
  $('#main p+p').css("color", 'green');
  $('#main p+h2').css("color", 'green');
  $('#main h2+h2').css("color", 'green');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="main">
  <h1>Main Heading</h1>
  <h2>Subheading</h2>
  <p>I am paragraph</p>
  <p>I am paragraph</p>
  <p>I am paragraph</p>
  <h2>I am heading 2</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: [Adjacent sibling combinator `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

Comment: Of your selectors, only `$('#main h2+h2')` won't be used